# Zoom in android cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-webview

I have a HTML5 web app and I want to create a Android app.

The first thing I did was to open Visual studio and make a simple app with a webview. In this case I am able to configure the zoom options of my webview.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

And everything works fine.

Then I want to create the same app usig cordova. The app works fine, but I cant make zoom, and I'm not able to configure the cordova webview... I tried to customize the Main Activity but I dont know how to acces to the settings of the Cordova Webview

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);

    WebSettings settings = this.appView.getSettings();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

with your answer I obtain this error:

```
C:\Users\xabier.esteban\Datavis\cordova\hello\platforms\android\src\com\example\
hello\MainActivity.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
                                            ^
symbol:   method getSettings()
location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
1 error
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.321 secs
```

Comment: I am also running into the same issue, can't enable pinch zoom in Android with cordova (using cordova 4.0). Tried all variations of the meta viewport tag. I distinctly remember Android zooming in previous cordova versions by adding the WebSettings code to MainActivity.java, but the getSettings() method seems to have disappeared from CordovaWebView. Would appreciate any workarounds.

Comment: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3313 : "we *introduced* `preference API` *to replace* `getSettings`. We need document this *new API* and help developers to migrate from getSettings". As I haven't found that API's documentation yet, this comment (instead of an answer) will have to do, at least now you know what to search for..

Answer (score 1):

in java file

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.os.Build;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.init();
            // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

            super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
            //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

            WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            {
                    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);

                    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            }
}
```

in html file use meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimum-scale=0.25, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Comment: This will not work, getSettings() is no longer exposed on CordovaWebView. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: nope. I ended up adding a zoom button that scaled up the map image by 2; not super happy with it and would still like regular zoom driven by user gestures

Comment: This worked for me, but note a deprecation notice. WebView wv_1 = (WebView)appView.getView();        
        
        wv_1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv_1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv_1.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that, as commented above, getSettings() is no longer exposed on CordovaWebView, but you can use this workaround (worked for me in addition to the viewport metatag)

```
WebView wv_1 = (WebView)appView.getView();        

wv_1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv_1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wv_1.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
```

hope this helps

also look at this from developer android site

> Note: If your targetSdkVersion is set to "18" or lower, WebView operates in "quirks mode" in order to avoid some of the behavior changes described below, as closely as possible—while still providing your app the performance and web standards upgrades. Beware, though, that single and narrow column layouts and default zoom levels are not supported at all on Android 4.4, and there may be other behavioral differences that have not been identified, so be sure to test your app on Android 4.4 or higher even if you keep your targetSdkVersion set to "18" or lower.

Comment: (WebView)appView.getView() returns null object